# get nested value from object in eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent

I'm using laravel's cashier in conjunction with stripe & from a collection of `Invoices` and I am trying to retrieve a specific Invoice by its `subscription` key :

```
Collection {#157 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Invoice {#162 ▼
      #owner: User {#163 ▶}
      #invoice: Invoice {#208 ▼
        +"id": "in_1BsZF2F3eLup6dYnvs74ij6B"
        +"object": "invoice"
        ...
        +"statement_descriptor": null
        +"subscription": "sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp"
        +"subtotal": 1999
        +"tax": null
        +"tax_percent": null
        +"total": 1999
        +"webhooks_delivered_at": 1517934260
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the function used by the `user` model to retrieve this collection of its `Invoices` :

```
public function invoices($includePending = false, $parameters = [])
{
    $invoices = [];

    $parameters = array_merge(['limit' => 24], $parameters);

    $stripeInvoices = $this->asStripeCustomer()->invoices($parameters);

    // Here we will loop through the Stripe invoices and create our own custom Invoice
    // instances that have more helper methods and are generally more convenient to
    // work with than the plain Stripe objects are. Then, we'll return the array.
    if (! is_null($stripeInvoices)) {
        foreach ($stripeInvoices->data as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->paid || $includePending) {
                $invoices[] = new Invoice($this, $invoice);
            }
        }
    }

    return new Collection($invoices);
}
```

Each `Invoice` object has two properties, the `Owner`(current user) and the actual `Invoice`

what is the proper syntax to drill down to each `Invoices` `subscription` key and check against that value?

I have attempted the following query and its resulted in `NULL` :

```
$user->invoices()->where('subscription','sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp')->first();
```

**UPDATE**

when I dump the following query `$user->invoices()->first()->subscription` it returns the correct string in `sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp` , however when i attempt to check against it using `$user->invoices()->firstWhere('subscription', 'sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp')` its results in `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$id = 'sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp'
$user->invoices->first(function ($invoice) use ($id) {
    return $invoice->invoice->subscription === $id;
});
```

It looks like you're just missing the nested invoice property on the actual invoice object in your attempt with where. This may work:

```
$id = 'sub_CH7UxbgcTCeHLp';
$user->invoices()->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('invoice.subscription', $id);
})->first();
```

Comment: i get a slew of `php warnings` : `Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::where()` , `  Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::operatorForWhere()` , `Undefined variable: operator` `PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`